# How to find the current context in which Appium is running?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

I am automating a hybrid application using Appium. 
Below code can be used in Java to find the set the appropriate context.

```
String context = driver.getContext();
```

What is the equivalent code in C#?

Answer (score 1):

If you use an IDE, you should be able to see all commands available to the driver object.

One place to take a look at all defined commands outside IDE is here: https://github.com/appium/appium-dotnet-driver/blob/master/appium-dotnet-driver/Appium/AppiumDriverCommand.cs#L179

```
driver.GetContext()
```

Comment: I am using Visual Studio. But I am not able to see GetContext. What all packages I need to use?

Comment: You need to include the appium-dotnet-driver package, which I linked up there. It includes the GetContext command, which is Appium specific. GetContext is not found in the Selenium package, as contexts are mobile only.

Answer (score 0):

in C# there is no method called getContext() like Java, instead, you can use a property called Context to get the current context and to switch to another context by assigning the context - which to switch - value to this property.

```
    public ReadOnlyCollection<string> Contexts { get; }
    public string Context { get; set; }
```

for example: if you want to get the current context:

```
string s = driver.Context;
```

if you want to switch to a webView you can try this

```
driver.Context="WEBVIEW_<PackageName>";
```

in case you need to get all available contexts in the current view use "Contexts" property

```
public List<string> GetContexts()
    {
        List<string> AllContexts= new List<string>();
        foreach (var context in (driver.Contexts))
        {
            AllContexts.Add(context);
        }
        return AllContexts;
    }
```